# Strange output when calling object function in loop (Python)

Tags: python

I created a class whith a method that print out one of it's fields:

```
class Rule:
def __init__ (self,number, callout):
    self.number=number
    self.callout=callout

def shout(self):
    print(self.callout)
```

I then create a list of these objects to iterate over, calling shout() for each of them:

```
Fizz = Rule(3,"Fizz")
Buzz = Rule(5,"Buzz")
Rules = [Fizz,Buzz]
#example 1
for x in range(0, 2):
    Rules[x].shout()
#example 2
for item in Rules:
    print (item.shout())
```

The output of example 1 is:
Fizz
Buzz
as expected. But the output of example 2 is:
Fizz
None
Buzz
None

Why do they perform differently?
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`item.shout()` returns a value of `None`

Therefore, when you print it, you'll get the print statement from the function as well as the return value which by default, is `None`